# Need to decrease my text size that is being displayed on my laptop for outlook and other icons on the laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a lenovo laptop with windows 10 installed and somehow I was busy with a document and must have touched one of the keys on the keyboard which resulted in my words being extra large - my outlook wording is huge as well as the titles on the icons on my laptop.
Please help - how can I get this back to normal size again?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Could you provide a screenshot of said issue?  There a number of things that could be causing things to look bigger.

Comment: Is the screen resolution still what it should be?

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought you hit the key combination

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>+</kbd>

or

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>MouseWheel Up</kbd>

(It actually resizes desktop icon size as well on Windows 10.)

But it could possibly also be the Windows font % size.

Please open `Display Settings` (search for display settings in the Start menu) and check what your text size % is set to. Usually it defaults to 100% or 125% depending on the monitor.